# F# Expr.TryGetReflectedDefinition with overloaded methods

Tags: reflection, f#, funscript

I'm writing some extensions for the FunScript project (F# to Javascript compiler). If you're interested you can find the source [here](https://github.com/alfonsogarciacaro/FunScript.HTML).

I was trying to emulate the AwaitObservable extension by [Tomas Petricek](https://github.com/tpetricek/FSharp.AsyncExtensions/blob/master/src/Observable.fs). However, if I use overloaded methods like `AwaitObservable(w), AwaitObservable(w1,w2)...` I get the following error when I try to compile a project to Javascript:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.AmbiguousMatchException' occurred in FSharp.Core.dll

Additional information: Ambiguous match found.
```

FunScript keeps a cache dictionary of the reflected definitions in the project, and this error occurs when it tries to add a new one to the cache using `Expr.TryGetReflectedDefinition`. The error disappears if I use different names instead of overloads (`AwaitObservable2, AwaitObservable3...`). That's the workaround I'm using now, but I would like to know more about the problem and whether is possible to fix it so the users of the extensions can use overloaded methods normally.

I can imagine that Reflected Definitions in F# don't support overloaded methods and cannot distinguish methods just by the number of arguments (I couldn't check that because I didn't find the implementation of `Expr.TryGetReflectedDefinition` in the fsharp GitHub source repository). However, what puzzles me is that the error doesn't happen when looking for AwaitObservable but the following method:

> {System.IDisposable
>   System-IObservable`1-Subscribe(System.IObserver`1[FunScript.TypeScript.MouseEvent])}  System.Reflection.MethodBase
>   {System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo}

So my questions are:

1. Why is `Expr.TryGetReflectedDefinition` failing with `IObservable.Subscribe` instead of `Async.AwaitObservable`?
2. Why is `Expr.TryGetReflectedDefinition` throwing an exception instead of returning None?
3. Is this a bug of F# Reflected Definitions or an unavoidable limitation? Is it possible to fix it?

Thanks a lot in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it seems this has no easy answer so I'll try to reply my own question. After further investigation...

1. It seems that because of the `Async.AwaitObservable` overloads the stored Reflected Definitions somehow (this 'somehow' is what remains unexplained) lose track of the type implementing `IObservable`, and that's why they do not know which implementation of `Subscribe` should be used.
2. I guess this is intended behaviour: returning `None` means the Reflected Definition has not been found, but here there was an ambiguous match so it's a different case.
3. I don't know yet if this is a bug or a 'feature', but in any case I fixed the problem in this particular situation using the `CompiledName` attribute and giving a different name to each overload. Now everything works fine :)

I hope next time I post a question that can actually be answered ;) Thanks to everybody who took the time to read this.